# Discrete Random Variables Help in Understanding

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

> A company wants to form a team of 6 employees. Suppose that 60% of
>   all staff available for selection are male, and that all team members
>   are selected at random. Let X be the random variable for the final
>   number of men on the team.
>
> (i) What distribution does X follow and why? Specify parameter values.

Any idea what type of distribution X follows? In my notes, I have $$x~~follows~ n( μ, \frac{δ}{\sqrt(n)})$$ next to the question. No idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there are $3m$ male members and $2m$ female staffmembers available for the selection.

Then $X$ has hypergeometric distribution and: $$P\left\{ X=k\right\} =\frac{\binom{3m}{k}\binom{2m}{6-k}}{\binom{5m}{6}}$$
The larger $m$ is, the better it is approximated by the binomial
distribution with parameters $p=0.6$ and $n=6$ giving: $$P\left\{ X=k\right\} =\binom{6}{k}0.6^{k}0.4^{6-k}$$
Note that the binomial expression does not depend on $m$.